# How to return the json object in the flask server side from socket client using python?

Tags: python, flask, socket.io, flask-socketio

On my client side, I have dataJson, and I want to sent this to server through socketio. On the Server side, I want this dataJson to be received and returned under the app.route in order to display it in the web.

Code on the server side:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask_socketio import SocketIO

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'vnkdjnfjknfl1232#'
socketio = SocketIO(app)

@app.route('/')
def sessions():
    print(dataJson)
    return dataJson

@socketio.on('my event')
def handle_my_custom_event(json):
    global dataJson
    dataJson = json
    print('received json: ' + str(json))

if __name__ == '__main__':
   socketio.run(app, debug=True, host='127.0.0.1')
```

Code on the client side:

```
from socketIO_client import SocketIO

import json
dataJson = {'xxx': 'yyy'}
with SocketIO('localhost', 5000) as socketIO:
    json = json.dumps(dataJson)
    socketIO.emit(json)
    print(json)
```

Or is there any other method to achieve my goal?
Thanks!

I solve this problem.

```
Code on the server side
from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask_socketio import SocketIO
import json
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'vnkdjnfjknfl1232#'
socketio = SocketIO(app)

dataJson = None

@socketio.on('my event')
def handle_my_custom_event(json):
    global dataJson
    dataJson = json
    print('received json: ' + str(json))

@socketio.on('my event')
def handle_my_custom_event(json):
    global dataJson
    dataJson = json
    print('received json: ' + str(json))

@app.route('/')
def sessions():
    global  dataJson
    print(dataJson)
    print(type(dataJson))
    Data = dataJson.decode('utf-8')
    JsonData = json.loads(Data)
    print(JsonData)
    print(type(JsonData))

    return JsonData

if __name__ == '__main__':
   socketio.run(app, debug=True, host='127.0.0.1')
```

Code on the client side

```
import json
import socketio



sio = socketio.Client()

def send_ping():
    while True:
      x = 1
      x=x+1
      jsonData = {'aaa': x}
      Data = json.dumps(jsonData).encode('utf-8')
      print(type(Data))
      sio.emit('my event', Data)

@sio.event

def connect():

    print('connected to server')

    send_ping()

if __name__ == '__main__':

    sio.connect('http://localhost:5000')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this is the only problem with your code, but the client-side `emit` call is missing the event name. It should be something like this:

```
socketIO.emit('my event', json)
```

Also note that you are using a variable called `json`, which will shadow the `json` package. Change it to a different name to avoid bugs that are difficult to catch.

Finally, I may want to suggest that you use the Socket.IO client from the python-socketio package instead of the one you are using. The python-socketio package includes a server and a client. The server is what you are using as part of the Flask-SocketIO extension, so you would be using a server and a client that are written by the same person (i.e. me, so I'm biased).

Comment: Thanks your reply, your answer works for me. And also I try Socket.Io for my client side and it works really well!